# How can I convert a .dxf file into .json using python?

Tags: python, json, blender, dxf

So basically I'm working on Blender on a set of 2D entities saved in a .dxf file. I need to read some points from the .dxf file in Blender using Python to later measure the distances between them (they usually are the turning points of the polyline) and they don't seem to have a specific name that could help me identify them.

I read about dxf-parser but it implies the use and knowledge of Node.js, thus I'd need to do it in Python.
Eventually, I'd also accept some advices on how to execute a Node.js script within python that would convert my .dxf file into a json.

Comment: I suggest googling "dxf parser python". It looks like there is a Python library that may be helpful for you.

Comment: see https://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/getting_data.html

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: Node.js is a framework that utilizes packages from everywhere, including python. You never use Node.js directly to do such conversion work since such work should belong to a specific package (no matter it is some who developed it already or something that you work on) like python.

I am also working on the same project that does the same conversion, which is pretty intuitive and straightforward. The practice that I took is:

1. create a python package that does the conversion job as a whole
2. import ezdxf package from https://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introduction.html
3. read the document on the website that gives you the basic concepts of how to access attributes/classes like layers, tables, entities
4. extract the attributes you need by a simple for loop for a .dxf file
5. export the entire object and convert it to a json file

I have a code snippet that briefly tells you how to extract layers for a .dxf file, which you may have a look for reference:

```
from datetime import datetime
import json
import sys
from typing import Optional, Tuple
from unittest.mock import _ANY
from ezdxf.filemanagement import readfile


class Scanner:
    

    __filename: str = ''
    __version: str = ''
    __output: dict = {}
    __layer: dict = {}
    __current_layer: dict = {}

    def print(self):
        print(self.__output)

    def __init__(self):
        return

    def read_file(self, file: str):
        

        # read the name of the file as string
        # & update it for the private variable
        self.__filename = file
        self.__output['name'] = self.__filename
        try:
            # store the dxf file as 'Drawing' class into __content
            # self.__content = readfile('%s.dxf' % file, errors='ignore')
            self.__content = readfile(file)
        except IOError:
            # print('Not a DXF file or a generic I/O error.')
            print(IOError.strerror)
            sys.exit(1)
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            print('Illegal sequence of str characters')
            sys.exit(2)

    def analyze(self):
        
        print('analyzing...')
        self.__output['Date'] = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        self.__output['Unit'] = str(self.__content.units)
        self.analyze_layers()
        # self.analyze_entities()
        # print(self.__output.get('Date'))
        print('analyze finished')

    def analyze_layers(self):
        

        handle: _ANY
        owner: str
        name: str
        flags: str
        color: str
        true_color: str
        line_type: str
        plot: str
        line_weight: str
        plotstyle_handle: str
        material_handle: str
        rgb: Optional[Tuple[int, int, int]]
        description: str
        transparency: float

        print('analyzing layers...')

        doc = self.__content

        # extract information within layers &
        # store them within a dict
        for layer in doc.layers:
            self.__current_layer['handle'] = layer.dxf.handle
            self.__current_layer['owner'] = str(layer.dxf.owner)
            # name_binary = layer.dxf.name
            # name_utf8 = name_binary.encode('ascii').decode('utf-8')
            # self.__current_layer['name'] = str(name_utf8)
            self.__current_layer['name'] = layer.dxf.name
            self.__current_layer['flags'] = str(layer.dxf.flags)
            self.__current_layer['color'] = str(layer.color)
            self.__current_layer['true_color'] = str(layer.dxf.true_color)
            self.__current_layer['line_type'] = str(layer.dxf.linetype)
            self.__current_layer['plot'] = str(layer.dxf.plot)
            self.__current_layer['line_weight'] = str(layer.dxf.lineweight)
            self.__current_layer['plotstyle_handle'] = str(
                layer.dxf.plotstyle_handle)
            self.__current_layer['material_handle'] = str(
                layer.dxf.material_handle)
            self.__current_layer['rgb'] = layer.rgb
            self.__current_layer['description'] = layer.description
            self.__current_layer['transparency'] = layer.transparency
            # store __current_layer dict to self.__current_layer
            self.__layer[str(layer.dxf.name)] = self.__current_layer
            # reset self.__current_layer
            self.__current_layer = {}
        self.__output['layers'] = self.__layer
        print('layer analyze finished')

    def analyze_entities(self):
        

    def analyze_images(self):
        

    def tojson(self):
        

        # Serializing json
        json_object = json.dumps(self.__output, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
        with open("sample.json", "w", encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
            outfile.write(json_object)
        print(json_object)
```